# Strange maven behavior when adding class to project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Whenever I create or change a classname in my project, I can't build my project until I do a maven update on account of this error when trying to execute maven build or install:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project app-webservice: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Development/app-webservice/src/main/java/test/app_webservice/controller/SoapRequestController.java:[19,51] package org.yaml.snakeyaml.external.biz.base64Coder does not exist
[ERROR] symbol:   variable Base64Coder
[ERROR] location: class test.app_webservice.controller.SoapRequestController
[ERROR] /C:/Development/app-webservice/src/main/java/test/app_webservice/controller/RestResponseController.java:[95,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable Base64Coder
```

This is from the package `org.yaml.snakeyaml.external.biz.base64Coder`.

It's a very annoying kink that I have never had before on a maven project, does anyone have any idea where it might be coming from?

I'm using maven version 3.3.9 and the Eclipse IDE version Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).

My POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-webservice</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>app-webservice</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>


  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>1.20</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-releases</id>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-releases</id>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you add pom.xml becuas now is not clear what you doing in maven.

Comment: @SauliusNext - Done, I should add, Maven Central is configured as global repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

package `org.yaml.snakeyaml.external.biz.base64Coder` does not exist means that you do not have the dependency specified in your pom file or is not discoverable by maven.

Comment: That is strange. As said in my question this ONLY happens whenever I change the name of one of my classes or add a new one. I run a maven update and it works. As you can see in the pom.xml I have the entirety of snakeyaml in my dependencies as well, which the package in question is a part of (I did go to maven central and double checked, even went with the new version of it, problem still persists)

Comment: It's not as though it doesn't work at all, it's just a very annoying kink that I have to run maven update whenever I change anything about my projects classes.